# How can i sort a table using VBA code which consists of a blank column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to sort a table in a worksheet using VBA code but there is a blank column in the table and columns after that blank column are not getting sorted.

```
Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Sort Key1:=Range("G2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Actually what is happening, the above VBA code is sorting columns till column before the blank column but not the columns which is after the blank column.

Comment: Do your keystrokes. You are telling it.

Comment: You need to use a `Range` object for the `Sort` method that includes the entire range you wish to sort.  If there is an empty column, your `.End(xlToRight` will stop at that column.

Comment: If your data is the only thing in that sheet you could use Sheets(x).usedrange (where x is your sheet name or index value

Comment: thanks guys for your comments, i am now able to run my code and results are as expected.